# One of Emily Bronte's sentence

Tags: meaning

> 'She frowned; and looking up, answered -
>   '"Mr. Hareton, and the whole set of you, will be good enough to understand that I reject any pretence at kindness you have the hypocrisy to offer! I despise you, and will have nothing to say to any of you! **When I would have given my life for one kind word, even to see one of your faces, you all kept off.** But I won't complain to you! I'm driven down here by the cold; not either to amuse you or enjoy your society."
>   '"What could I ha' done?" began Earnshaw. "How was I to blame?"
>   <sub>*Wuthering Heights*, chapter 30</sub>

I'm specifically wondering about this sentence:

> *When I would have given my life for one kind word, even to see one of your faces, you all kept off.*

What is the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? I'd guess it is the part about "faces", but you haven't specified.  Try to understand in context. Remember this is a writer 200 years ago. Can you get the general mood of the speaker?

Comment: Can you kindly paraphrase this sentence? I am not native speaker.

Comment: Could you try to paraphrase the sentence first. Then we might understand what it is that you are having difficulty with.  Have you read the rest of the book up to here? Do you remember the story?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language of the passage is a bit old fashioned, a bit stilted, and more than a bit hyperbolic.

**When I would have given my life for one kind word, even to see one of your faces, you all kept off.**

Non-hyperbolic, flat paraphrase.

**When I was desperate for kindness and company, you stayed away from me.**

Less flat paraphrase with the original hyperbole.

**When I would have gladly died in return for one kind word, even for a silent companion, you kept yourselves apart from me.**

Comment: OHH i get the general idea

Comment: I like the answer.